# Can't see parent children from single child KIVY

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I want to update a variable from LogViewScreen with DeployScreen. Each class is a tab/child in my NucleusPanel which inherits TabbedPanel. I notice when I iterate of the children of the parent class (NucleusPanel) I can only see the child for which I am currently using to iterate over the children. How can I access all the children of my parent from either tab?

```
class DeployScreen(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeployScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ....
    def getTaskList(self, event, tasklist):
        for c in self.parent.children:
            print(c)
        # update LogViewScreen button text
        self.parent.ids.LogViewTab.selected_tasklist = tasklist
        ....


class LogViewScreen(RelativeLayout):
    selected_tasklist = StringProperty(" ")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogViewScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # defaults
        self.canvas.clear()

        self.ViewingIndicatorBox = Button(
            text=self.selected_tasklist,
            size_hint=(1,None),
            size=(self.size),
            )

        self.ViewingIndicatorBox.disabled = True
        self.add_widget(self.ViewingIndicatorBox)
        return(None)

    pass

class NucleusPanel(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NucleusPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tab_pos = "top_left"
        self.tab_width = 265

        self.default_tab_text = "Deploy"
        self.default_tab.id ='DeployTab'
        self.default_tab_content = DeployScreen()

        self.lv_tab = TabbedPanelHeader(text='Log Viewer')
        self.lv_tab.id = 'LogViewTab'
        self.add_widget(self.lv_tab)
        self.lv_tab.content = LogViewScreen()

   pass


class NucleusApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return(NucleusPanel())
```

I expect to be able to be able to see all children under NucleusPanel from DeployScreen, but I only see DeployScreen:

```
<__main__.DeployScreen object at 0x000002262937DCE0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all the tabs by looping through the `tab_list` using:

```
    for c in App.get_running_app().root.tab_list:
        print(c.content)
```

You can use this anywhere in the `App`.

Comment: Brilliant! With this, I should be able to update widgets within each tab from another tab, correct?

Comment: you just opened up a whole new world for me! I can pretty much do as I please with this.

Answer (score 0):

To update my ViewingIndicatorBox widget within my LogViewScreen from the DeployScreen I simply create and id for that button and using the help I received, I can iterate through the content for each tab and pin my search down to the the child of Button instance with the respective id. Here is how I did it.

```
class DeployScreen(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeployScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ....
    def getTaskList(self, event, tasklist):
        for c in NucleusApp.get_running_app().root.tab_list:
            if 'LogView' in str(c.content):
                for child in c.content.children:
                    if isinstance(child, Button) and child.id == 'VIB':
                        child.text = tasklist
                        ....

class LogViewScreen(RelativeLayout):
    selected_tasklist = StringProperty(" ")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LogViewScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # defaults
        self.canvas.clear()

        self.ViewingIndicatorBox = Button(
            id='VIB',
            text='Current running log - {}'.format(self.selected_tasklist),
            size_hint=(1,None),
            size=(self.size),
            background_normal='',
            background_color=[0.18, 0.18, 0.31, 1],
            pos_hint={'top':1},
            height=50
            )
```